# Linq where with ternary and brackets

Tags: c#, linq, ternary

I have the following query:

```
return Postcodes
            .Where(
                s => s.Postcode.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 &&
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) ? true : s.CountryRegionID.Equals(country, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            )
            .Select(p => new { label = p.Postcode, value = p.RecID })
            .ToList();
```

Now I would have expected this to return all postcodes matching both country and term but for some reason it only matches the term if the country is null and then if the country isn't null, it ignores the term and just matches the country.

If I put brackets around the ternary:

```
return Postcodes
            .Where(
                s => s.Postcode.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) ? true : s.CountryRegionID.Equals(country, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            )
            .Select(p => new { label = p.Postcode, value = p.RecID })
            .ToList();
```

Then it works exactly as I would expect.  Why does the extra pair of brackets make a difference as code analysis always complains about me putting brackets around ternaries?

Comment: Why dou you use the conditional operator for that? You just need: `...&& (string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) || s.CountryRegionID.Equals(country, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter good point I will change that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C# ternary operator has lower priority than conditional AND operator. Thus without brackets AND evaluated before ternary operator and you have ternary operator which checks postcode AND country. I.e. by default

```
( checkPostcode && countryNotNull) ? true : checkCountry
```

When you add brackets you split ternary operator which checks country from postcode check

```
checkPostcode && (countryNotNull ? true : checkCountry)
```

See [7.2.1 Operator precedence and associativity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the links.  Will accept this when it allows me